# SSH Config for using a jumpserver

Tags: ssh, server

I have a problem with the configuration of a jumper server in ssh_config.

So far I was able to configure the connection for a server as follows:

```
Host myhost*
        ProxyCommand ssh -q myjumpserver nc %h %p
```

So I could reach via ssh myhost1 or ssh myhost2 directly my two servers.

Now unfortunately something has changed and I should call my servers with the following syntax:

```
ssh user@newjump@myhost1
```

(yes 2x `@` is correct and only this notation works)

`Newjump` is not a jumpserver in the real sense, so I can't use the syntax above.

Does anyone have an idea how I can configure this?
Since I have >30 servers and these groupwise always have the same naming scheme, it would be nice if I could generalize it as above. But in case of doubt I would also implement a solution for each individual server.

What is important to me is that I only have to type `ssh myhost1` to reach this host. A solution via alias is out of the question, because then I would have to adapt numerous scripts.

Comment: I'm not even sure how `ssh` would parse that destination. Is it equivalent to `ssh -u user newjump@myhost1`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by
Host name1
Hostname newjump
User user@host1